# Pandas memory usage inconsistencies

Tags: python, pandas, memory

I have some memory inconsistencies when I am using a Pandas DataFrame.

Here is my code skeleton:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns_dtype = {'A': np.int16, 'B': np.int8, ...}
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', dtype=columns_dtype)
```

That is basically just reading a csv file with pandas while controlling column data types. But then, when I am looking for how much memory is allocated to my program, the information does not seem coherent.

**Info 1:**

```
df.info(memory_usage='deep')
```

That gives : `memory usage: 482.6 MB`

**Info 2:**

```
import dill, sys
sys.getsizeof(dill.dumps(df))
```

That gives : `506049782` (so 506 Mb)

**Info 3:**

The RAM allocated to my program is : 1.1 GiB (or 1.2 Gb)

**Additional info** (but i do not think it is relevant):

the size of my_file.csv is 888 Mb (ls -lh)

**The issue:**

As I am just loading my csv file into a Pandas DataFrame object, why does my program needs more than 1 Gb of RAM whereas the object size is about 0.5 Gb ?

Many thanks

Comment: What is the relevance of the `dill.dumps`? Why do you think the `dill`/`pickle` serialized dataframe would take exactly the same amount of memory as the dataframe?

Comment: No, I just wanted to check the order of magnitude of the pickled object. It matches approximately the size of the pandas object, so it means df.info(memory_usage='deep') does not under evaluates the size of pandas objects. Moreover, sys.getsizeof(dill.dumps(df)) and sys.getsizeof(df) are the same

Comment: Because parsing csv's can require a lot of auxilliary memory. Check out the `pd.read_csv` options.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to pretend to know the deep underlying use of dynamic memory to hold data in Pandas.  Pandas is hungry when it loads large flat files, as a rule of thumb, pandas will use 5-10x the amount of ram as the file size you're loading to do analysis on.

To avoid these you can chunk the data when loading:

```
  df = pd.load_csv(file_path, chunksize = 30000)
```

or if you're doing analysis down columns:

```
  df = pd.load_csv(file_path, usecols = list_of_columns_index)
```

or both!

```
  df = pd.load_csv(file_path, chunksize = 30000, usecols = list_of_columns_index)
```

Hope this helps speed up your analysis.